# Passing variables in PHP from one file to another

Tags: php, sql, variables

So this is my code. Now how do I use $pubname in another file.

```
mysqli_select_db($connect,"membership");
$retname = "select username from users where email='$globalname' limit 1";
$rn = mysqli_query($connect,$retname) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
$name = mysqli_fetch_array($rn);
    //connecting for mathcing username with fullname and displaying it
$pubname = mysqli_real_escape_string($name['username']);

include('profile.php');

echo $pubname;
```

and also is this code secure? I did that...does not work yet.

Comment: You don't need to escape strings FROM the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Include the file you would like the variable to be accessible within, like so

```
include('somefile.php')
```

and at the top of that file *you might* need put something like [depending on server configurations]

```
global $pubname
```

But in most cases you would not need to do this.

In regards to security, depending on how `$pubname` is set, your query *may or may not* be prone to `sql injection.`

Note: There are other means to `include()` files such as `include_once()`, `require()` and `require_once()`, from [php.net](http://php.net):

> The documentation below also applies
>   to require(). The two constructs are
>   identical in every way except how they
>   handle failure. include() produces a
>   Warning while require() results in a
>   Fatal Error. In other words, use
>   require() if you want a missing file
>   to halt processing of the page.
>   include() does not behave this way,
>   the script will continue regardless.
>   Be sure to have an appropriate
>   include_path setting as well. Be
>   warned that parse error in required
>   file doesn't cause processing halting
>   in PHP versions prior to PHP 4.3.5.
>   Since this version, it does.

Answer (score 1):

To use `$pubname` in another script, keep it as global variable. You don't need to echo it. (As caveat: global variables should be used sparingly, preferrably lumped into an array.)

As far as security is concerned: You should use `mysqli_real_escape_string` rather on `$globalname` right before you use it. And escape the `$pubname` only right before you use that in the next query. As it looks now, you are encoding the output needlessly, but forgot to do escape the input - which `_escape_string` is actually meant for.

Answer (score 0):

to use `pubname` in a nother file. first you have to include the file where `pubname` was set/created.

then use `include()` or `require()` function to call it.