# How can I reference variables from another included file in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, include

So I'm working on a PHP app and trying to make everything moduler.  I have an index.php file that includes other php files.  The first file included is settings.php which has my postgres credentials defined so they can be accessed elsewhere. The second file is connect.php that has a function you can pass sql to and it will return $result.  The third file has functions that call the sql function and receive $result and parse it.  In the third file, I can read the results of the $result however if I try if($result) it breaks and isset/empty have no effect.

Anyone have any ideas on a way to make this work, or is my structure just terrible?

Thanks so much!

Mike

Comment: How does it break? Please post the error message that you get.

Comment: Please post examples of your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675932/passing-a-variable-from-one-php-include-file-to-another-global-vs-not

Comment: Agreed - need more info. However, in general, including files that create variables that are used in other files, or including files that rely on a variable created in another file are both roads to misery. Global scope is bad enough, when you mix in multiple files then you're just asking to spend time figuring out what went wrong instead of writing code.

Answer (score 0):

let's say you have the following three files:

**inc1.php**

```
<?php
  $foo = 'hello';
?>
```

**inc2.php**

```
<?php
  echo $foo;
?>
```

**main.php**

```
include('inc1.php');
include('inc2.php');
```

it should echo "hello". however, passing variables around among files is a bad idea, and can lead to a lot of confusing, hard-to-follow code. If you need to pass variables around, use functions and/or objects so that you can at least see where they are coming from.

beyond that though, it's difficult to tell exactly what your problem is without seeing the code in question.

Answer (score 0):

I would really try to switch to OOP. This makes things a lot of easier. If you just have to deal with classes, their methods and attributes you only have to include the classes and not this choas of functions. So I would recommend, give it a go ...