# PHP how to pass `http request` object from one PHP file to another PHP file

Tags: php, redirect, location, request-object

usually when i want to redirect from one `php` page to another php page of same project i'm using

```
header("location:somepage.php");
```

This will cause more calls between client and server. What i want to do is instead of sending redirect header, i want to stop execution of requested page and pass request object or request information to the another page which i want to redirect. In this case single request will be enough. I guess this kind of functionality available in `jsp`. Is same thing available in php which i don't know?

Comment: If it is on the same site as the first PHP, you could just include the PHP from your first one.  Or are you wanting to pass the request information to a php file on a different site?

Comment: if you want to keep track of intermediate data/status, consider using [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DanSherwin commented, you probably want to use [include](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php). You might do something like this:

firstpage.php:

```
if(/* Some condition when you want to do a redirect */){
    include 'somepage.php';
    exit;
}
```

This runs the code from `somepage.php` immediately, as though it was cut and pasted into `firstpage.php`**, and then it exits right afterward as though you redirected away from `firstpage.php`.

** caveat: [watch out for variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675932/passing-a-variable-from-one-php-include-file-to-another-global-vs-not).