# PHP Using a variable from an include

Tags: php, include

I got a simple PHP code like this one:

```
<div id="master">
    <div id="info">
        <?php include 'division.php';
        echo $winrate;

        ?>
    </div>

    <div id="lastmatches">
        <?php include 'lastmatches.php';?>
     </div>



 </div>

</body>
```

As you see i want to echo $winrate, but $winrate is a variable that comes from lastmatches.php. So it will never work. Some has got an idea to echo $winrate in the div info? Im stuck and i hope you guys can help me out!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$winrate` cannot be shown when it is defined in the future.  Include lastmatches.php before you echo it.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675932/passing-a-variable-from-one-php-include-file-to-another-global-vs-not
use `global $winrate;`

Comment: But if i include it earlier its an problem with the HTML and CSS?

Comment: Only if you echo out stuff in lastmatches.php.

Comment: Structure your code properly so you can get the value of `$winrate` without it also outputting a bunch of HTML. If your problem is that the two are intertwined, you need to decouple those two things.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `lastmatches.php` before to define `$winrate`.
But if this file outputs some content then you will want to use the caching system to output the right content at the right place.

```
<div id="master">
    <div id="info">
        <?php include 'division.php';
        // begin cache
        ob_start();
        include 'lastmatches.php';
        // end cache
        $lastmatchescontent = ob_get_clean();
        echo $winrate;

        ?>
    </div>

    <div id="lastmatches">
        <?php echo $lastmatchescontent; ?>
     </div>



 </div>

</body>
```

Comment: I'd call it output buffering rather than caching, because it's not preserving pages to save processing time.

Comment: Indeed, it's just that the first time I have heard about this method it was called `caching` so it kind of stayed in my mind. But your term is more exact.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to follow MVC approach, if you do not want to use framework u can do something like this: https://github.com/LPodolski/basic_php_templating

this will allow code to be more readable, by separating concerns of generating output from getting data from db, parsing it etc