# include files which has same variable names

Tags: php

A.php

```
define("_a_","hey!");
```

B.php

```
define("_a_","wow!");
```

index.php

```
function getFile($type) {
  include_once($type . ".php");
  echo _a_;
}
```

Calling getFile

```
getFile(A); //--> Output "hey!"
getFile(B); //--> Output "hey!" HERE IS THE PROBLEM, SHOULD ECHO "wow!"
```

Then I exchanged the order  of calling functions

```
getFile(B); //--> Output "wow!"
getFile(A); //--> Output "wow!" HERE IS THE PROBLEM, SHOULD ECHO "hey!"
```

Thanks for all helps

Comment: Check out the answer, and if it was helpfull check it as Accepted - StackOF Community will thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [PHP official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php):

```
bool define ( string $name , mixed $value [, bool $case_insensitive = false ] )
```

> Defines a named **[CONSTANT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_%28computer_programming%29)** at runtime.

So if it defines not changable value, that means you cannot change the value at runtime.

**EDIT**: 
You can use variables to get data from included files. When you are including scripts you are basically creating new script with copy & pasted content from included file and executing that new script. [Passing a variable from other script - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675932/passing-a-variable-from-one-php-include-file-to-another-global-vs-not)

Comment: That's true I'm okay with that but it shouldn't be problem because i'm include the file dynamicly in function. I mean when passing "A", getFile function include A.php and if I pass "B" then getFile should include only B.php

Comment: Just to expand on [what is a constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_%28computer_programming%29), `a constant is an identifier with an associated value which cannot be altered by the program during normal execution`. You can read more about [php's implementation here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php).

Comment: @user3645649 On the php constant page: `Like superglobals, the scope of a constant is global. You can access constants anywhere in your script without regard to scope.` Defining a constant in a function is still defined in global scope.

Comment: thanks @JonathanKuhn. I need to do this, how can i do that ?

Comment: what about creating variables?

Comment: unfortunately must be constant and i need to do something inside getFile function. Is it possible to remove included file or constants when the function is die ?

Comment: You can still use them outside the file with var declarations. When you are including- you are basically creating new script with copy & pasted content from inculuded file.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675932/passing-a-variable-from-one-php-include-file-to-another-global-vs-not

Comment: @Toumash thank you, I handled with creating variables