# Using a PHP variable in included file evaluates to NULL in included file

Tags: php, css

I am trying to process some CSS using PHP. The CSS I want to process is page-specific and so I want to set a variable in my `index.php` to only echo the CSS when the variable is set.

**index.php**

```
<?php
    $name = 'index'; 
?>
<?php
    include 'inc/header.php';
?>
```

**header.php**

```
<head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title></title>       
<?php include 'import.php'; ?>
</head>
```

**import.php**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css.php" type="text/css" />
```

The header is properly set for this file. and the CSS is interpreted.

**styles.css.php**

```
.jumbotron {
    background-image: url(../img/jumbotron.jpg);
    <?php 
        if ($name === "index") { 
            echo("height: 50VH;"); /* Does not echo anything*/
        }
        var_dump($name); // Evaluates to NULL
    ?>
}
```

How can I make sure `$name` is set to it's value, as set in `index.php`?

---

**EDIT**: My final solution was to make an object from the `stdClass` and add the variables I needed as attributes to the object. putting a GET request in the link to the CSS file which was the Base64 of the JSON string of the object.

Comment: try with global $name

Comment: did you include the index.php to styles.css.php?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675932/passing-a-variable-from-one-php-include-file-to-another-global-vs-not

Comment: That's because `$name` is not defined in styles.css.php. You should also enable error reporting because this should have produced a warning.

Comment: @LorenceHernandez That fixed it, but now there is  a complete PHP file present in my CSS file. And that's not really what I want.

Comment: @StrahinjaDjurić I have used `$GLOBALS['name'] = $name` in `index.php` but that did not fix it. the `styles.css.php` still dumps `NULL` when I var_dump `$GLOBALS['name']`.

Comment: @MegaXLR You really seem to have no clue what's going on here. I suggest you read the http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php manual page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<link>` tag makes an HTTP request for a file totally independent of the PHP pages that are including each other, so `$name` is not available in styles.css.php.

To do it this way you need to link the style sheet something like this to pass `$name` as a get variable:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css.php?name=<?php echo $name; ?>" type="text/css" />
```

Then in the style sheet styles.css.php use `$_GET['name']`:

```
    if ($_GET['name'] === "index") { 
        echo("height: 50VH;");
    }
```

Comment: Fixed it! Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are linking to that **styles.css.php** from inside the rendered html. This means that page will be fetched in a separate request (as you can se when you inspect the page). This request never passes trough your **index.php**, and so the `$name` variable will not be set.

I would advise you to include the css in the rendered HTML inside a style block. It should be as easy as changing your **import.php** to this:

```
<style>
<?php include 'css/styles.css.php' ?>
</style>
```

This also has the added benefit of reducing the number of requests the browser has to make, and should therefore speed up the page.

This is btw not a very standard method of using css. I believe it would be better to add some sort of id (or data attribute) on your `body` tag that indicates the name of the page you are on. In the css file (that does not run trough php, just a standard css file), you could then do something like this:

```
.jumbotron {
    background-image: url(../img/jumbotron.jpg);
}
#index .jumbotron {
    height: 50vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The file `styles.css.php` does not *know* about the `$name` variable - that's why it is *null* when doing the `var_dump($name)`. With your `<link>` you just output the content of your style.css.php as plain html/css. You need to do either an `include_once('styles.css.php')` or a `require_once('styles.css.php')` so that you can properly evaluate the `$name` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are having an HTML page generated by `index.php`. This tells the browser to load the external style sheet at the line `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css.php" type="text/css" />`. Loading external data by the browser is a completely new request. Thus the PHP file generating the style sheet does not know anything about the variables declared in the script serving the HTML page.

Actually the variable $name is unset. Since it is given as argument by reference to `var_dump` (the builtin function is declared to take arguments by reference), the reference results in `null`.

If you want to distinguish between different style sheets in only one PHP script, append a GET parameter to the URL as query:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css.php?name=<?PHP echo $name;?>" type="text/css" />
```

Take that parameter in *syles.css.php*:

```
<?php $name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : ''; ?>
```