# Echo variables from another file in php

Tags: php, echo

I have a PHP file containing some variables and need to echo them multiple times in another file.

file1:

```
<?php
//some calculating going on
$var1 = 5;
$var2 = 2;
?>
```

file2:

```
<?php 
echo $var1;
echo $var2;
?>

<?php 
echo $var1;
echo $var2;
?>
```

How could this be achieved?

Comment: Include file1 into file2 to by using: include "file1.php";     just below <?php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a variable from one php include file to another: global vs. not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675932/passing-a-variable-from-one-php-include-file-to-another-global-vs-not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file2.php should [`include("file1.php")`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), like:

**file2.php**

```
<?php 
include("file1.php");
echo $var1;
echo $var2;
?>
```

Assuming they're both in the same directory.

Comment: probably worth mentioning `require()` as well

Comment: I have updated the question. Including the file in every <?php ?> would case the calculations in file1 to be calculated multiple times, thus falsify the outcome.

Comment: Just `include()` it right after your first `<?php` and you'll be able to use them multiple times in your whole file.