# Not able to pass variable from different php file

Tags: php

This is not duplicate of this [Passing a variable from one php include file to another: global vs. not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675932/passing-a-variable-from-one-php-include-file-to-another-global-vs-not)

I am trying to make a simple php project where I have different file for DB connection(config.php), DB functions(db_functions.php), normal functions(functions.php) and index file(index.php).

I have DB connection set up in config.php -

```
$link = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME) or die(mysqli_error());
```

This connection works properly(tested on index.php). DB_HOST and other constants are declared in config.php file. Now, I have my php files connected like this -

1. functions.php is required(using require) in index.php
2. db_functions.php is required(using require) in functions.php
3. config.php is required(using require) in db_functions.php

Now, if I want to use the `$link` variable in db_functions.php, it doesn't work. Shows a notice `Undefined variable: link in db_functions.php on line 10`.

I am calling the `$link` in a function on db_functions.php Declaring `global $link` once on db_functions.php doesn't work either. I have to declare `global $link` in every function on db_functions.php. This is annoying, is there any way  to avoid using it so many times? Or work around without even declaring global?

Thanks in advance

Comment: yes you have to use the GLOBAL key word in every function, that's how it works, otherwise parse the $link variable to each function as an argument, or consider an OOP paradigm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What tim said is correct, one other approach without implementing OOP is using the superglobal `$GLOBAL`

ex.
`$GLOBALS['link']`

reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

Comment: Though it's not the answer I was looking for but as there are no other option in PHP, i have to go with OOP or $GLOBALS['link']