# PHP: Error Undefined variable. Using variable from php file to another php file

Tags: php

```
//this is my connection.php
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;', 'root');
$pdo->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
?>


//this is my class.php
<?php
include 'connection.php';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare(query here); //wrong part
?>
```

problem: Error undefined $pdo, what is the right way in doing this? But when i transfer the code from the connection.php to class.php it works fine.

Comment: Well, first of all you should ensure that your connection.php is really included - maybe it's in another directory than class.php?

Comment: replace include with require,check if you are getting fatal error

Comment: YEs sir because if its not, there will be an error failed to open stream etc.. ^^

Comment: Try wrapping your PDO object construction in a `try {} catch()` block, as shown in example 2 on this page: [Connections and Connection management](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php). That might tell you if the object is failing to be created properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the `$pdo` as `global` in the above file `connection.php`.

Check [Passing a variable from one php include file to another: global vs. not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675932/passing-a-variable-from-one-php-include-file-to-another-global-vs-not) and [Passing variables in PHP from one file to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572062/passing-variables-in-php-from-one-file-to-another)

Comment: I don't think this should be the case. If he were including connection.php and then in connection.php trying to use `$stmt` then it should be the case I believe.

Comment: Read the answer on one of your links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675932/passing-a-variable-from-one-php-include-file-to-another-global-vs-not the answerer describes the global requirement for variable within inclusion functions

Comment: @Sammaye: I still did'nt get your point. But since this has now been accepted as an answer, i think this was what the OP was looking for.

Comment: To quote a comment from the answerer: `So, the parent file has access to variables in both included files, but the included file doesn't have access to the other included file.` Indeed it worked because of the global scope of it, however according to PHP semantics from linked questions it shouldn't be the right answer.